# Ruby - how to get rid of the last element in a string according to the following pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I have these kind of strings:

```
A regular sentence.
A regular sentence (United Kingdom).
A regular sentence (UK).
```

The goal is to remove the term in the brackets, thus the desired output would be:

```
A regular sentence.
A regular sentence.
A regular sentence.
```

How to achieve this in Ruby (probably with using regular expressions?)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
string.gsub(/\s*\(.*\)/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"A regular sentence (UK).".gsub(/\(.*\)/,"").strip #=> "A regular sentence ."
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the sentence itself can contain parenthesis:

```
a = "A (very) regular sentence (UK)."
p a.gsub(/\s\([^()]*\)(?=\.\Z)/, '') #=> "A (very) regular sentence."
```

Comment: This does not work for all the test cases the OP had. You should use `/\s\([^()]*\)(?=\.)/`.

Comment: Works for me if the dot at the end of the line is the end of the string. I interpret the wording as if he has 3 strings, not one.

Comment: Okay I see. It was not specified to be 3 separate strings, but it was not specified either it was not ;-)